# .NET 6 publishing Android Application

Tags: c#, android, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, maui

How do I publish an Android app in VS2022? I've started with the "Android Application (Preview)" template. It all runs fine in emulator. When clicking publish on the project only a *.nupgk is created. When clicking "View archives..." solution shows up but the only text is "No archive builds available" and I don't see any option to create one.

Edit: By publish I mean create *.apk that could be installed. I have no need to publish to Google Play or any other store.

Comment: I don't believe that Visual Studio has a way to directly publish the app to the Google Play store if you have this in mind.

Comment: Its not possible through the UI right now, only with the command line `dotnet publish` I'm working on some content to describe how, but wasn't able to finish it yet :)

Comment: @RandRandom no I just want *.apk or whatever can be easily installed on a phones. This is not even meant for broader public.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis In case you do, please tag me with a link.

Comment: This no good? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#archive-for-publishing

Comment: @RandRandom The issue is there is no posibility to "Archive". This shows VS GUI, though Gerald confirmed that there's no way to do it from there.

Comment: Wasn't sure if Gerald also thought about actual publish to google play store or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll clarify the question.

Comment: Oh if you have no need to actually go to the Play Store then let me add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

I have created guides now for each platform with what does and doesn't work and how to proceed with publishing on the .NET MAUI repository. Find the links here:

- [Android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4377)
- [iOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4397)
- [Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4329)

## Original answer:

As pointed out in the comments, I have been playing with this and I always got all the things complete and create some content, but not quite yet.

First; this is not possible at the time or writing from the UI. Of course this will be before .NET MAUI will be released, but for the time being you'll need the command-line, specifically `dotnet publish`.

You've already figured out that this command typically is used to create a nupkg, but to unify all the things, this is now also going to be used to *publish* your .NET MAUI apps.

The problem is that we now have a single-project that can be used for all kinds of targets: iOS, Android, Windows, macOs, so how do we know what `dotnet publish` should publish?

You'll need to specify the target framework. For Android that brings us to this:

`dotnet publish -f:net6.0-android -c:Release`

This should produce an APK that you can use. The one thing I'm not sure about yet is how to add your keystore file in the mix and actually sign it properly for use in the Play Store.

To make things complete, for iOS the command and process is a bit more complicated. The command, from Windows, would look more like this:

`dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress=192.168.1.77 /p:ServerUser=jfversluis /p:TcpPort=58181 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/{your username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/`

There are a couple of parameters that are only needed when you build from Windows: `/p:ServerAddress={Mac build host IP address} /p:ServerUser={Mac username} /p:TcpPort=58181` if you have never connected to this build host you should also add `/p:ServerPassword={your password}`. However, you could just go into Visual Studio, connect to the build host from there once and you'll know the connection works and the omit the password parameter. More on the Mac build host functionalities is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).

But we're not there yet! In the `csproj` file we need to add a little piece to add the `RuntimeIdentifier` and a couple of things to make the signing of the IPA file work.

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignEntitlement>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlement>
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Gerald Versluis (BLABLAID)</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>VS: WildCard Development</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The `Entitlements.plist` file is not part of the default templates (yet) so just take one from a Xamarin.Forms project, it can be the default one or, of course, configure it if you actually need it, but it seems you need it to be there either way.

The values for the code signing you need to get from the Apple certificates stuff. This is the part I'm not completely clear on yet as well. More info on code signing and provisioning is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/), that might help get you further.

For the iOS command, also have a look at the backstory [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3777). As seen in this link, you might also need to delete the `LaunchScreen.xib` file from the `Platforms/iOS/Resources` folder and potentially include the `/p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false` flag to the publish command to work around some bugs. Both of them are fixed but not yet released.

Disclaimer: I haven't published anything to a store yet so there might be gaps here, feel free to add some comments with your findings.

Comment: This answers the original question. As it produces APK that can be installed. But there seems to be more to making an actually usable app. I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package in the project and when publishing the app this just creates DLL in the folder where APK is created. When running the APK whenever the app requires this library app just crashes leading me to believe that it's not actually included. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here... You're saying installed plugins don't get included in the apk?

Comment: That's the way it looks to me. Though this happens only when publishing with the command you provided. When debugging in emulator everything works well.

Comment: Could you maybe reach out to me if it's not too much trouble? I'd love to see if we can fix it and/or if we have issues in this area that we need to address :) gerald.versluis@microsoft.com thanks!

Comment: After I looked into it I discovered I was wrong. TLDR; I missed an async statement and assumed I had it covered by try catch block. Not an compilation issue.

With that said I'm still having issues that I can't replicate in debug enviroment. Solved by really obscure things. For instance the underlying issue with CosmosSDK was solved completely randomly by installing Xamarin.Essentials. This is not related to the question and I don't know if that's of any interest to you or your team if you want me to provide stack trace or something just let me know as I don't want to spam you.

Comment: Yeah I'd still love to get in touch in terms of anything .NET MAUI related so we can see how people are using it and what they're running into, so please still reach out. I appreciate you being mindful of my time though!

Comment: [.NET MAUI Android target publishing/archiving](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4377) update from @GeraldVersluis